# Downloading multiple tickers data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I saw this code that Andrej Kesely posted on StackOverflow. I really find it very helpful, but I am trying to download multiple tickers instead of one ticker.  [Cannot scrape from table in yahoo finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263449/cannot-scrape-from-table-in-yahoo-finance?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Currently, I am downloading multiple tickers for prices, and I use the ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN'], so I tried to change

url = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL","https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=MSFT"]

It didn't work, I was wondering if anyone know how to change it for a url. Thank you so much.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for t in soup.select("table"):
    for tr in t.select("tr:has(td)"):
        for sup in tr.select("sup"):
            sup.extract()
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
        if len(tds) == 2:
            print("{:<50} {}".format(*tds))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `DataReader`?

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader # conda install pandas-datareader
data = DataReader(['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'MFST'], 'yahoo', start='2015-01-01', end='2021-08-30')
print(data)
```

Result:

```
Attributes   Adj Close                                            Close  \
Symbols           AAPL         AMZN         GOOG       MFST        AAPL   
Date                                                                      
2015-01-02   24.782110   308.519989   523.373108  22.000000   27.332500   
2015-01-05   24.083958   302.190002   512.463013  23.700001   26.562500   
2015-01-06   24.086227   295.290009   500.585632  23.700001   26.565001   
2015-01-07   24.423975   298.420013   499.727997  21.100000   26.937500   
2015-01-08   25.362394   300.459991   501.303680  21.100000   27.972500   
...                ...          ...          ...        ...         ...   
2021-08-23  149.710007  3265.870117  2821.989990   0.000800  149.710007   
2021-08-24  149.619995  3305.780029  2847.969971   0.000700  149.619995   
2021-08-25  148.360001  3299.179932  2859.000000   0.000800  148.360001   
2021-08-26  147.539993  3316.000000  2842.459961   0.000500  147.539993   
2021-08-27  148.600006  3349.629883  2891.010010   0.000400  148.600006
```

Comment: How would I change it for market cap etc.? Thank you.

Comment: See https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html for the remote data sources that are supported.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see a market cap, but there were other interesting ones.

Answer (score 1):

you can try also yfinace:

```
import yfinance as yf
etf = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO'] #and any tickers you'd add to be retrived
tit = yf.download(tickers=etf, period='max')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for:

- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT
- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/key-statistics?p=AMZN
- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPL/key-statistics?p=APPL

In that case, you can use the f-string:

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
for tick in tickers:
    print(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{tick}/key-statistics?p={tick}")
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I just replace url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL"
with 
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
for tick in tickers:
    print(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{tick}/key-statistics?p={tick}"

It's showing me an error

File "<ipython-input-7-086bd0df21ed>", line 9
    headers = {
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax